# Is there a performance difference between these two queries?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a lot of properties that return lists. I usually do them like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property activeSchedulesAsOf(ByVal target As Date) As List(Of schedule)
    Get
        Dim list As New List(Of schedule)

        For Each c As Contract In contracts
            For Each s As Schedule in c.schedules
                If s.isActiveAsOf(target) Then list.add(s)
            Next
        Next

        Return list
    End Get
End Property
```

Is there any benefit from doing it like this?

```
Public ReadOnly Property activeSchedulesAsOf(ByVal target As Date) As List(Of schedule)
    Get
        Dim list As New List(Of schedule)

        For Each c As Contract In contracts
            list.AddRange(c.schedules.Where(Function(s) s.isActiveAsOf(target)))
        Next

        Return list
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddRange` should *technically* be quicker because internally it calls `Array.Copy` rather than enumerating the collection if you are dealing with an `ICollection<T>` e.g. `List<T>`. In your case, since you are providing an `IEnumerable<T>` via the `Where` you would need to call `ToList` to get that implementation (otherwise it just internally enumerates).

Unless you are dealing with a lot of *really* big lists you probably aren't likely to see much of a difference. There are other things to consider besides performance though

- Readability
- Code length

The second one, in my opinion, is much neater and does it in less code (however, I just love using LINQ when I can!). However, you could also argue that it's slightly less readable than the first... it's really just down to personal taste.

Comment: It can only take the array shortcut when you actually give it a collection. Given a `Where` enumerable it will still insert sequentially.

Comment: @nmclean only if it doesn't support `ICollection<T>`, which `List<T>` does so a `ToList` would fix that, I have updated my answer.

Comment: But the list created by `ToList` would also be built sequentially, negating the time saved from `AddRange`. If we didn't need to filter the items then we could just do `AddRange(c.schedules)`, but since we do need to generate a different sequence, the nested foreach is probably more efficient because it only creates a single list. We can still do the same with LINQ though, if we flatten the sequence: `contracts.SelectMany(Function(c) c.schedules).Where(...).ToList()`